# Click not working, only touchstart mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How do I bind 'click' to a paragraph?

I have the following function:

```
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown',"p span.text", function(e) {
                             console.log('I was clicked');
                             *more code here*
});
```

If I replace 'touchstart mousedown' with 'click', the function is no longer fired.

PS: I'm SUPER new to JS, so I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    $("p span.text").on('click', function(){
          console.log('I was clicked');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I bind 'click' to a paragraph

Try to attach `click` event to your paragraph instead of `span`:

```
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown click',"p", function(e) {
    console.log('I was clicked');                 
});
```

Comment: By doing that, I pretty much get the same result as I did with just 'touchstart mousedown'. I would like to only fire the method when it's a click(tap), aka with a 300ms delay. If the user swipes the screen, I don't want the method to fire.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:
According to your reply, updated

```
$(document).on('click',"p span", function(e) {
         console.log('I was clicked');                                 
});
```

Comment: I wrote this: $(document).on('click',"p span", function(e) {
                                             alert('click happened'); but the alert isn't fired.

Comment: That site you sent me is awesome. However, it only works on that site, when testing in iOS simulator, it doesn't work...